# Pass a value from URL to iframe on same page

Tags: iframe

I am trying to pass a ZIP code value from the page URL to an iframe on the same page.
The page URL is:
mysite.com/page.html?zip=90210

and I'd like the iframe on that page to get the zip code value like this:
 src="http://www.adifferentsite.com/iframedpage?go=1&zip_code=90210

I've almost got it working using window.location.search but that is grabbing the whole string, not just the value (a 5 digit zip code).

I'm looking at javascript solutions but could do php as well.

Thanks in advance!
Tim

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id>.src = 'http://www.adifferentsite.com/iframedpage?' + location.href.match(/\?(.*)/)[1]
```

Would this work, or just grab the query string out with..

```
location.href.match(/\?(.*)/)[1]
```